# SQL aggregate function based on the result of another aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql-server

so really need help.I need to apply max aggregate function on result of count aggregate function, but the query I use keeps failing. I have two columns: president(lists the names of presidents), country(lists the names of countries); table name commission. I need to find the country that had the most number of presidents.

```
Select country, count(president) as number_of_presidents 
from commission where country=any(select max(number_of_president) 
from commission) 
group by country;
```

Any help much appreciated!Thanks

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: There are two columns one has the names of presidents, the other the names of the countries. Basically I need to count all the presidents for each country and then give only the names of the countries that had most presidents.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Top 1` instead

```
Select Top 1 country, count(president) as number_of_presidents 
from commission
group by country
Order by number_of_presidents desc
```

IF you are using `Mysql` remove `TOP 1` Change `order by` to

```
Order by number_of_presidents desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I would need to display only the max values for number_of_presidents, if 'desc' is used it displays all the values

Comment: @AnnBikovich - Am sure Top 1 will result only one row something else wrong did you use same query i suggested. Which database you are using.